# Trying to compile x64 assembly in VS2017 ml64 giving weird syntax error

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2017

I'm attempting to build a DXT Decompression library found here to a x64 DLL:
http://www.matejtomcik.com/Public/KnowHow/DXTDecompression/#x64

I've followed these steps:

1. Created an empty Windows DLL project.
2. Right clicked on the project >> Build Dependencies >> Build Customization... >> Enable masm
3. Added all the src asm/c/h files to the project
4. Right clicked on the project >> Properties >> Microsoft Macro Assembler >> General >> Preprocessor Definitions added _WIN64
5. Set build target to Release x64

Now when I try to compile the project it hits the very first asm file:

```
ifndef _WIN64
.model FLAT, C
endif
.data
EXTERNDEF aAlphaDxt3Lookup:DWORD
aAlphaDxt3Lookup DD 0h,011000000h,022000000h,033000000h,044000000h,055000000h,066000000h,077000000h
DD 088000000h,099000000h,0aa000000h,0bb000000h,0cc000000h,0dd000000h,0ee000000h,0ff000000h
end
```

and gives this error:

> A2008 syntax  error:. (line 2)

I'm assuming I've missed some setup step or have an incorrect option somewhere in VS.  I've tried toggling a couple of settings , adding .586 etc to no avail.

Edit: Question clarification: `Removing .model FLAT, C` fixes the syntax error and the asm file compiles correctly.  Does ml64 still use .mode?

From here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f4c79dbc-7048-4513-bd63-70352186512f/64bit-compile-error-language-type-must-be-specified?forum=vclanguage

> the x64 assembler (ML64) does not accept many of the older x86
>   directives.  All CPU model directives are not allowed as they dont
>   make sense for 64bit code.  Also, the model is now FLAT all the time
>   as we dont need to worry about segmented memory.  Also, be forwarned
>   that the PROC/INVOKE directives currently do not automatically
>   generate unwind directives...

Answer (score 0):

OK so found it:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ss9fh0d6.aspx

> **Remarks**
>
> .MODEL is not used in MASM for x64 (ml64.exe).

Really? in the remarks section...nice of MS to add a descriptive error message.